# How can I set Dockwidget floating mode window movable false?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QdockWidget which is in floating mode. I want this floating window steady at particular location(Window should not move threw drag/ or anyway). How can I get this?

Comment: have you tried `QDockWidget::setFeatures(DockWidgetFeatures features)`?